# SSRS - Show data based on user option Report by:(hour/day/month/year/daypeak)

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have the DB table that stores customername, hourly values (0-23) and reading dates  all meters. I created a SSRS report that gets the hourly data from the table based on the date range (start & enddate)

Report Design has the following parameters:

```
Start Date:
End Date:
Customer: Dropdown list that show all our active customers
Report By: Dropdown list that show (Hour/Day/Month/Day Peak/Month Peak/Year Peak)
```

End user selects date range (start & end), customername and Reportby:Month. I should be able to show the report based on user selected option (report by:).

I created a dataset under query have this query:

```
SELECT CustomerName, ReadingDate, IntegratedHour, IntegratedUsage, IntegratedGeneration
FROM         DB.dbo.TableName
WHERE     (DATEADD(HOUR, IntegratedHour, ReadingDate) BETWEEN DATEADD(HOUR, 0, @StartDate) AND DATEADD(HOUR, 23, @EndDate)) AND 
                      (CustomerName = @FacilityName)
ORDER BY ReadingDate, IntegratedHour
```

This query results me the hourly values.

How do i filter or bring this to show report by Day/month/Year based on end-user selection. I am not sure where to set the filter or how to query.

Could someone help me on this. Appreciate your help/advises. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your Day Peak/Month Peak/Year Peak definitions are but hopefully this can help.

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '2017-01-01'
      , @EndDate DATETIME = '2017-12-02'
      , @FacilityName VARCHAR(50) = 'Peter'
      , @ReportBY VARCHAR(20) = 'Month'

DECLARE @TestData TABLE (CustomerName VARCHAR(50),ReadingDate DATETIME,IntegratedHour INT,IntegratedUsage DECIMAL(15,2),IntegratedGeneration  DECIMAL(15,2))
INSERT INTO @TestData
SELECT 'Peter','2017-01-01',1,20,33
INSERT INTO @TestData
SELECT 'Peter','2017-01-01',2,21,33
INSERT INTO @TestData
SELECT 'Peter','2017-01-01',3,22,33
INSERT INTO @TestData
SELECT 'Peter','2017-02-01',3,22,33


SELECT CustomerName
     , CASE WHEN @ReportBY = 'Hour' THEN IntegratedHour 
              WHEN @ReportBY = 'Day' THEN ReadingDate
              WHEN @ReportBY = 'Month' THEN MONTH(ReadingDate)
              WHEN @ReportBY = 'Day Peak' THEN ReadingDate
              WHEN @ReportBY = 'Month Peak' THEN ReadingDate
              WHEN @ReportBY = 'Year Peak' THEN ReadingDate
              ELSE  ReadingDate END As DateType
     , SUM(IntegratedUsage)
     , SUM(IntegratedGeneration)
FROM  @TestData
WHERE (DATEADD(hh, IntegratedHour, ReadingDate) BETWEEN DATEADD(hh, 0, @StartDate) AND DATEADD(hh, 23, @EndDate)) 
    AND (CustomerName = @FacilityName)
GROUP BY CustomerName
       , CASE WHEN @ReportBY = 'Hour' THEN IntegratedHour 
              WHEN @ReportBY = 'Day' THEN ReadingDate
              WHEN @ReportBY = 'Month' THEN MONTH(ReadingDate)
              WHEN @ReportBY = 'Day Peak' THEN ReadingDate
              WHEN @ReportBY = 'Month Peak' THEN ReadingDate
              WHEN @ReportBY = 'Year Peak' THEN ReadingDate
              ELSE  ReadingDate END
```

Comment: Snowlockk, Thank you so much for your code. Appreciate it.

Here is the scenario, when the user selects date range, facility and Hour/Day/Month/Year/.. from the dropdown list on the SSRS report, it should generate the report as follows:

Day Peak - Highest/Max(value) for the days selected. IntegratedUsage, IntegratedGeneration.

MOnth Peak - Highest/Max(value) from IntegratedUsage, IntegratedGeneration for each month 

Year Peak - Highest(value) from IntegratedUsage,IntegratedGeneration for the year.

Comment: Just to clarify, On the ReportBy Parameter, do you want me to specify the values for Hour as Hour, Day as Day, Month as Month and so on?

Comment: Couldnt get it working, appreciate any help on this. Thanks.